# how to match dataframe column with list and create a new column with elements from list

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas df column which has some text. Now I want to compare each word of this text with elements from list and if there is a match then I want to add that word in a new column. Although, I am able to extract these using loop(although not ideal) but when it comes to text where there is no match, I am not able to append none. for ex.

python list:
bodyparts = ['thumb', 'back', 'elbow', 'shoulder', 'ankle', 'hamstring', 'knee']

Also, The following expression doing the job only partially and just appending 0 or 1, if there is a match or no match receptively.

input_file_1['bodyparts'] = input_file_1['Description'].apply(lambda x: sum(i in bodyparts for i in x.split())).................
can I use any other expression, which can actually append the matched word?

Although, I am able to extract these using loop(although not ideal) but when it comes to text where there is no match, I am not able to append none.

Also, The following expression doing the job only partially and just appending 0 or 1, if there is a match or no match receptively.

input_file_1['bodyparts'] = input_file_1['Description'].apply(lambda x: sum(i in bodyparts for i in x.split()))

### expected output

### bodyparts

### thumb

### back

### elbow

### none

### actual output

### 1

### 1

### 1

### 0

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will do the job.

```
bodyparts = ['thumb', 'back', 'elbow', 'shoulder', 'ankle', 'hamstring', 'knee']

def search_bodyparts(s, bodyparts):
    found_bodyparts = [bodypart for bodypart in bodyparts if bodypart in s]
    if len(found_bodyparts)>0:
        return ', '.join(found_bodyparts)
    else:
        return None

df['bodyparts'] = df['Description'].apply(lambda x : search_bodyparts(x, bodyparts))
```

Comment: Thanks Xavier for the prompt response. However, the expression still not appending "None", if there is no match. Is there any way that I can add  "None" to the column.

Comment: This will still do a job, and I will get the empty cell, which later can be treated as missing values.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the function and it will return None if no bodyparts are found

Comment: Its perfect now. Thanks a tonne for the help.

Comment: This function works alright, when I am using smaller data set, but throwing the following error while I am using for complete data set.  "argument of type 'float' is not iterable"

Comment: You just have to put `[str(bodypart) for bodypart in bodyparts if bodypart in s]` instead of the code in the answer and it will work.